# Can We Create Custom Login Page In Azure AD B2C (User Flow or Custom Flow)

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, msal-react

I haved an ReactJs app that I want to use AAD B2C to manage Identity for my users.
I created the AAD B2C tenant, then registered application type SPA, then I can login using this example repo: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-tutorial/tree/main/3-Authorization-II/2-call-api-b2c/SPA.

I wonder that can I custom this login page, for example I wrote a login page in my react app contain my Logo and my site main color, I want the login page follow that style.

Comment: Have you checked the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To create the Custom login page, refer this
> [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow) as suggested by *junnas*.

I created a **sample custom HTML page** like below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE  html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Form</title>
<link  rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"  href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h2>Login Page</h2><br>
<div  id="api"></div>
<div  class="login">
<form  id="login"  method="get"  action="login.php">
<label><b>User Name
</b>
</label>
<input  type="text"  name="Uname"  id="Uname"  placeholder="Username">
<br><br>
<label><b>Password
</b>
</label>
<input  type="Password"  name="Pass"  id="Pass"  placeholder="Password">
<br><br>
<input  type="button"  name="log"  id="log"  value="Log In Here">
<br><br>
<input  type="checkbox"  id="check">
<span>Remember me</span>
<br><br>
Forgot <a  href="#">Password</a>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I created an **Azure Storage account** and uploaded the **`customize-ui.html`** file in the container like below:

[image]

And configured the **CORS policy** like below:

[image]

When I tested the CORS policy, I got the **`200 OK`** response:

[image]

Now *Go to Azure AD B2C User Flow -> Page Layouts -> Set Use custom page content as YES*:

[image]

**When I run the user flow, the custom page is displayed successfully like below:**

[image]