# Microsoft Entra External Id - Is it possible for an external customer to login with username-password?

Tags: .net, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-entra-external-id

I wanted to use a custom login form in a .NET Core web application in which the users will provide their username and password to login (acquire access token) into a **Microsoft Entra External Identities** tenant. I have already seen the [ROPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) flow as presented for the B2C, but its limitations are a stopper for me. Can someone please provide any suggestions if this is possible and how?

Comment: What if those external users have multi-factor authentication enabled? How would they enter the code received? The ROPC flow won't allow it.

Comment: You are right. Let's suppose integrated MFA is not needed for the login or could be a custom solution. If that's true, is what I am asking possible without ROPC in Entra External Id?

Comment: You can make use of authorization code flow which will ask user to enter Username and password

Comment: That authorization code flow is achieved through a custom policy, right? I just wanted to use my own custom login form for the user to enter username and password. Is that possible or using this flow will present to the user the Microsoft's login form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: I agree with you, ROPC flow isn't recommended due to security reasons. Hence as a workaround you have to make use of other user interaction flows such as Authorization code flow.

I created an Azure AD Application and granted API permissions:

[image]

To authenticate the users, I used the below endpoint:

```json
https://b2caadtenant.b2clogin.com/b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_testb2c/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/xxx/test.read.all
&state=12345
```

Based on the requirement you can either sign-in or sign-up:

[image]

The user will be redirected to the redirect page and the **auth-code** will be generated:

[image]

I generated the **access token** using below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://b2caadtenant.b2clogin.com/b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_testb2c/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/1xxx/test.read.all openid offline_access
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
code:code
```

[image]

> That authorization code flow is achieved through a custom policy,
> right? I just wanted to use my own custom login form for the user to
> enter username and password. Is that possible or using this flow will
> present to the user the Microsoft's login form?

Yes, by default using this flow it will present the user the Microsoft's login form, to **customize the login form** follow this [**SO Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76053329/can-we-create-custom-login-page-in-azure-ad-b2c-user-flow-or-custom-flow/76100397#76100397) by me.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Assuming that I wanted to use the Entra External Id and not B2C, and also the MSAL library through .NET, is what you describe possible? Also, I don't see the options to customize the page layout in the Entra admin portal. Maybe they haven't added it all yet since it's in preview.

Comment: Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/how-to-customize-branding and https://www.thijoubert.com/2023-02/AzureAD_LoginPage/